# Is it compulsory to download Visual Studio for spacy?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I have tried installing spacy, but it is throwing the below error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

I don't want to install Visual Studio. Is there other way to resolve this?

Comment: visual studio build tools != visual studio

Comment: where i need to put this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, installing spaCy requires a compiler. On Windows, this is included in the [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). (Not to be confused with Visual Studio – you definitely don't need the whole thing.)

If you install spaCy from conda, you should be able to install binary wheels, which don't require a compiler:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

Providing binary wheels for pip is definitely on the spaCy roadmap – you can follow the discussion and work in progress [in this thread](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1843).

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same thing but however managed to do it without MS Build Tools. However the process requires a bit of manual effort, but that's worthy if you don't want to waste space for MS Build Tools.

1. Visit [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#spacy). Here you can get many binary wheels of a number of python packages for various python versions and both for 32/64 architectures.
2. Next search and download ujson, cymem, murmurhash, preshed, cytoolz, thinc and finally spaCy.
3. Install each wheel in the downloaded order using `pip install some-package.whl`

Hopefully spaCy will be installed successfully. If not, please leave a comment and I'll try my best to help you out.